# C# Regex a string with format 12.34.56 in a long string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have a following strings

```
<tr><td>2015-003517</td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td><td>09.01.2015</td><td width="12">&nbsp;</td><td>JP</td></tr>
```

I want to select the first string match this format 12.12.1234 with regex. I've tried `^(\d{2}.\d{2}.{4})` but doesn't work.

Comment: is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: 1) don't - use an html parser. 2) remove the `^` from your pattern.

Comment: Don´t parse HTML with regular expressions, use an Html-parser instead.

Comment: also, `var match = Regex.Match(input, @"12\.12\.1234");` matches the format "12.12.1234"

Comment: @Sam sorry Im new to this coding things and I'm not really good at English, I found out the way by Neil's post. Anyway thank you and nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The `^` assertion says "Match must be at the beginning", so you should remove that.

Also, `.` means "match any character" but you want it to mean "match a . character" so you need to escape it with a `\`

Otherwise, you're ok. This matches against your numbers:

```
(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})
```